# What is meaning of blue dot in the left gutter in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch

I am new to Git and working with Git in VS Code. I created some branches and you can see them in the below image

[image: git branches]

Why does branch b3 have a blue dot? what does it mean? I use VS Code, can we see this behavior in other editors?

Comment: Is that a text file, or a terminal (powershell?) ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is inside of vscode terminal (powershell of windows actually).

Comment: Try clicking it? Maybe it's a breakpoint?

Comment: they are also shown in the [Terminal Basics](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics) doc page. I remember a release note talking about it and what it means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the [shell integration decorations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration#_command-decorations-and-the-overview-ruler), but just weirdly misaligned- it's usually aligned to the shell prompt's first line or somewhere near there.

It'll probably disappear if you put `"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled": "never"` in your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). In older versions of VS Code, the setting takes a boolean instead of a string enum. At the time of this writing, the setting's description from defaultSettings.json says:

> ```json
> // When shell integration is enabled, adds a decoration for each command.
> //  - both: Show decorations in the gutter (left) and overview ruler (right)
> //  - gutter: Show gutter decorations to the left of the terminal
> //  - overviewRuler: Show overview ruler decorations to the right of the terminal
> //  - never: Do not show decorations
> "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled": "both",
> ```

You can also see the release notes that mention shell integration updates (google "`site:code.visualstudio.com/updates shell integration`"). For example, [for 1.65](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65#_terminal-shell-integration), where it mentions that there are three types of decorations: blue for success, red for error, and empty/grey for default.

Given that I get three different issue tickets as the top search results when googling "`github vscode issues shell integration decorations misaligned`", I'm not exactly surprised that you're seeing weird behaviours. If you want to help with issue reporting, take a look through existing issues to see if what you're seeing here is covered already or not, and if it isn't, [report a new one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug_report.md).

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue.
I tried changing the settings.json file as suggested by starball.

Although, as I [checked](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration#_command-decorations-and-the-overview-ruler), the mentioned configuration setting (terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled) has the following valid values in JSON - string ('both', 'gutter', 'overviewRuler', 'never').

`"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled" : "never"` ✅
worked for me

Comment: I've updated my answer post.